# Difficulty in getting elements from a pop up window when using selenium in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the authors name and his affiliation from the webpage (given below in the code). In some cases, the number of authors can be large and there is a button 'Show_all' which we can click to see all the authors name.

```python
driver_max_wait_time = 20

driver.get('https://inspirehep.net/literature?sort=mostrecent&size=25&page=1&q=arXiv%3A1311.4916')

# Wait for the element.
WebDriverWait(driver, driver_max_wait_time).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'result-item-title')))

# click the above element.
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'result-item-title').click() 

# Get the name of authors and their affiliations. May be in format a(U), b(U) etc.
# a, b are authors.
# U is some university.
WebDriverWait(driver, driver_max_wait_time).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '__InlineList__')))
auth_and_aff_text = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '__InlineList__').text

if 'Show All' in auth_and_aff_text:
    print(' Do somehting special')
    WebDriverWait(driver, driver_max_wait_time).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, '__SecondaryButton__'))).click()
    #Now we have clicked the show_all button.
```

As can be seen in the snippet that `show_all` button was clicked. Can someone tell me how can I extract authors name from this small window/popup.

As was asked by someone, I am further editing question to include screen shots.

The first `driver.get` command i.e. `https://inspirehep.net/literature?sort=mostrecent&size=25&page=1&q=arXiv%3A1311.4916` leads to the following page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjfwO.png)

Now, we click the paper title which leads to the following page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJF6d.png)

Now we click the show_all button which open the small window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ErVz.png)

This is where I am stuck. How to extract information from this window/popup?

Comment: Will you show some screenshots of what you see in the webpage as you do these actions manually?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have added screen shots as per your comment. I do not have enough score on this website to post images directly. Therefore, you will see links to the screen shots. Hope this would be helpful. Let me know if you need any other infromation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names=[x.text for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ant-modal-body']//a[@data-test-id]")]
```

Should grab all 9 names in that popup without the brackets if that's what you want.

or for with brackets

```
//div[@class='ant-modal-content']//div[@class='di']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my query. I was actually looking for the solution which will grab the text with brackets. I was confused that I would need to switch to a new frame and then select some data. But after seeing your answer, I noticed that clicking show_all activates some fields which we can grab as you have mentioned above.